# This js code is not working in html file. But, same js code works when I paste the code at console

Tags: javascript, html, console, javascript-objects

`console.log(document.querySelector("button").value);`
not working in `html` file. But same codes work when I pest it in console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      console.log(document.querySelector("button").value);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button value="my value">click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my first time in stackoverflow. sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: You should add JS after the HTML? JS won't find the element because HTML hasn't loaded yet...

Comment: Welcome to SO. The script is running before the DOM has loaded. Move the script to just before `</body>`.

Comment: now it's working .Why it was not working then?

Comment: because your script load before the ```DOM```.

Answer (score 0):

**`Document.querySelector` will not find a match if it is run before any elements have loaded.**

You can use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event listener to only run the code after the `Document` has been loaded.

**Demo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      console.log(document.querySelector("button").value);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button value="my value">click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you trying to do , but if you want that my value be shown in the console when you will click on the button , you can do this by :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang="en">
<head>
<script>
  function press(){
  return console.log(document.querySelector("button").value);}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="press()" value="my value">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```